# Java parse nested Object

Tags: java, algorithm

I’m stuck on an algo.

I’d like to parse a `Map<?,?>` which could be like this:

```json
"test": {
     "input":{
          "data": {
               "content1": {
                        "value": "value1"
               },
               "content2": {
                        "value": "value2"
               }
         },
         "meta": {
              "metaContent": "content"
         }
    }

}
```

What I’d like is a new Map<String,String> containing every path of the nested object with it value.

("test.input.data.content1.value", "value1");

("test.input.data.content2.value", "value2");

("test.input.meta.metaContent", "content");

Thanks for help me to perform this :)

Comment: Where are you stuck (a recursive approach should work)? And is the input a `Map<?,?>` or a `Map<String, ?>`? It also helps to show the code that you already have

Comment: For now i retrieve this ("test.input.data.content1.value", "value1"); with a recursive method. But i don’t know how to get content2 or meta. Input is a Map<?,?>

Comment: What should happen if the key isn't a String, but another type?

Comment: We don’t treat it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some psuedocode of a recursive solution:

```
ParseObjImpl(obj, parent, keyValuePairs):
  for key in obj.keys()
    if obj[key] is an object:
      ParseObjImpl(obj[key], parent + key + ".", keyValuePairs)
    else:
      keyValuePairs.push([parent + key, obj[key]])

ParseObj(obj):
  keyValuePairs = []
  ParseObjImpl(obj, "", keyValuePairs)
  return new Map(keyValuePairs)
```

Comment: Why thinking too hard, works great thanks !